# Transitioning from glyphicon to input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I am trying to achieve this functionality that is one of freecodecamp's goals : https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/wGqEga/
Specifically, I want to transition the search icon to a form with input text, and then transition back to the search icon when user clicks on the X. I do not know if I am on the right track, but when I click on the search icon no transition is taking place. Thank you very much for your help!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#SearchBar i').on('click', function(){
      $('#SearchBar').html('<form><input type="text" style="border: none;"><span> X</span></input></form>');
       $('#SearchBar form').toggleClass('clicked');
       $('input').toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

```css
body#bootstrapOverride {
  background-color: rgba(255, 10, 10, 0.8);
}

#random_page{
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: 240px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#SearchBar{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 232px;
  width: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  transition-property: width, border-radius, border, padding;
}

#SearchBar form.clicked{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  left: -120px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input{
  width: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: width 2s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: width 2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: width 2s linear 0s;
  transition: width 2s linear 0s;
}
input.clicked{
  width: 200px;
}
span{
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: papyrus;
  -webkit-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
}

#genericText{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 240px;
  color: white;
  font-type: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"> </script>

<body id="bootstrapOverride">
  
<div class="container-fluid" id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <h1 class="text-center"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="_blank" id="random_page"> Click here for a random article </a></h1>
        <div id="SearchBar">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="glyph">     </i>
        </div>
        <div id="child4">  
      <h1 id="genericText" class="text-center"> Click on icon to search </h1>
        </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope it will work for you. So please try this option.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"> </script>
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var submitIcon = $('.searchbox-icon');
            var inputBox = $('.searchbox-input');
            var searchBox = $('.searchbox');
            var isOpen = false;
            submitIcon.click(function(){
                if(isOpen == false){
                    searchBox.addClass('searchbox-open');
                    inputBox.focus();
                    isOpen = true;
                } else {
                    searchBox.removeClass('searchbox-open');
                    inputBox.focusout();
                    isOpen = false;
                }
            });  
             submitIcon.mouseup(function(){
                    return false;
                });
            searchBox.mouseup(function(){
                    return false;
                });
            $(document).mouseup(function(){
                    if(isOpen == true){
                        $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
                        submitIcon.click();
                    }
                });
        });
            function buttonUp(){
                var inputVal = $('.searchbox-input').val();
                inputVal = $.trim(inputVal).length;
                if( inputVal !== 0){
                    $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','none');
                } else {
                    $('.searchbox-input').val('');
                    $('.searchbox-icon').css('display','block');
                }
            }
  </script>
  
  
  <style>
  body#bootstrapOverride {
  background-color: rgba(255, 10, 10, 0.8);
}

#random_page{
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: 240px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#SearchBar{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 232px;
  width: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  transition-property: width, border-radius, border, padding;
}

#SearchBar form.clicked{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  left: -120px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

span{
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: papyrus;
  -webkit-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
}

#genericText{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 240px;
  color: white;
  font-type: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.searchbox{
    position:relative;
    min-width:50px;
    width:0%;
    height:50px;
    top: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: width 0.3s;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.3s;
}

.searchbox-input {
    top: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
    width: 200px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
}
.searchbox-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #d74b4b;
}
.searchbox-input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #d74b4b;
}
.searchbox-input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #d74b4b;
}
.searchbox-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #d74b4b;
}
.searchbox .searchbox-icon img{display:none;} 
.searchbox-open .searchbox-icon img{display:block !important;} 

.searchbox-icon {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 22px;
    right: -10px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #dcddd8;
}
.searchbox-submit {
    background: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    background: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/search-128.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
.searchbox-open .searchbox-submit {
    background: unset;
}
.searchbox-submit img, .searchbox-icon img{
width:22px;
}
.searchbox-open {
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
form.searchbox input.searchbox-input {
    display: none;
}
form.searchbox-open input.searchbox-input {
display: block !important;
background: #fff;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
color: black;
}

  </style>
</head>
<body id="bootstrapOverride">
  
<div class="container-fluid" id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <h1 class="text-center"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="_blank" id="random_page"> Click here for a random article </a></h1>
        <form class="searchbox">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search......" name="search" class="searchbox-input" onkeyup="buttonUp();" required>
        <input type="submit" class="searchbox-submit" placeholder="">
        <span class="searchbox-icon"><img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/navigation/close_black_144x144.png"></span>
    </form>
      <h1 id="genericText" class="text-center"> Click on icon to search </h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! I believe this is on the right track to my goal, thanks! I am wondering why there is a text of "Please fill out this field" on the top left corner of the screen if I press on the search icon sometimes? Edit: I see how it happens, if I click on the left side of the icon, that text appears. Where does this text come from in the code?

Comment: Actually, In this field have added a required attribute for the validation which is the attribute of html form. If you don't have need of this then you can remove it from first input element.                                                                                     

If is this the right answer for you as per your need can you please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add and remove classes on click of close button next to input box and also clicking on the search icon.

Here is a demonstration below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#close').on('click', function() {
    $("#glyph").removeClass('f_out_g');
    $("#form_div").removeClass("enlarge");
  });
  $('#glyph').on('click', function() {
    $("#glyph").addClass('f_out_g');
    $("#form_div").addClass("enlarge");
  });
});
```

```css
body#bootstrapOverride {
  background-color: rgba(255, 10, 10, 0.8);
}

#random_page {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: 240px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#SearchBar {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 232px;
  width: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  transition: all 2s linear 0s;
  transition-property: width, border-radius, border, padding;
}

#SearchBar form.clicked {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  left: -120px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input {
  -webkit-transition: width 2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: width 2s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: width 2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: width 2s linear 0s;
  transition: width 2s linear 0s;
}

input.clicked {
  width: 200px;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: papyrus;
  -webkit-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
  transition: font-size 2s linear 0s;
}

#genericText {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 240px;
  color: white;
  font-type: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#f {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.4s left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
}

#form_div {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

.enlarge {
  transform: scaleX(1) !important;
  z-index: 5;
}

#glyph {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  z-index: 2;
}

#f:hover #glyph {}

.f_out_g {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  z-index: 0;
  
}

form * {
  font-size: inherit
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js">
</script>

<body id="bootstrapOverride">

  <div class="container-fluid" id="parent">
    <div id="child">
      <h1 class="text-center"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="_blank" id="random_page"> Click here for a random article </a></h1>
      <div id="SearchBar">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="glyph">     </i>
        <form id="f">
          <div id="form_div">
            <input type="text" style="border: none;"><span id="close">X</span>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="child4">
        <h1 id="genericText" class="text-center"> Click on icon to search </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```